# How to group datetime into intervals of 3 hours in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, aggregate-functions, mysql-8.0

I have the follwoing table structure

| start | count |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-08-02 22:13:35 | 20 |
| 2022-08-03 04:27:20 | 10 |
| 2022-08-03 09:21:48 | 10 |
| 2022-08-03 14:25:48 | 10 |
| 2022-08-03 14:35:07 | 10 |
| 2022-08-03 15:16:09 | 10 |
| 2022-08-04 07:09:07 | 20 |
| 2022-08-04 10:35:45 | 10 |
| 2022-08-04 14:42:49 | 10 |

I want to group the `start` column into 3 hour intervals and sum the count

like follows

| interval | count |
| --- | --- |
| 01h-03h | 400 |
| 03h-06h | 78 |
| ... | ... |
| ... | .... |
| 20h-23h | 100 |
| 23h-01h | 64 |

I have the following query but am not sure how to proceed from here

```
select hour(start), sum(count) from `table`
GROUP BY hour(start)
```

Comment: Try playing with something like GROUP BY FLOOR(hour(start)/3) If you divide by 3 and floor you'll get 3 hour groups. Now to play with that number to report the correct hour span like *3 and *3+2 or using MIN and MAX with concat.

Comment: do you want to include intervals that have no rows?  if so, what does `select version();` show?

Comment: @ysth I am running mysql 8

Comment: That didn't answer my question.  And your sample output is very confusing in a number of ways.  Please show sample data and *desired output for that data*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this you need to be able to take any DATETIME value and *truncate* it to the most recent three-hour boundary. For example you need to take `2022-09-06 19:35:20` and convert it to `2022-09-06 18:00:00`.

Do that with an expression like this:

```
DATE(start) + INTERVAL (HOUR(start) - MOD (HOUR(start), 3)) HOUR
```

This truncates the value to the nearest DATE(), then adds back the correct number of hours.

So a query might look like this:

```
SELECT DATE(start) + INTERVAL (HOUR(start) - MOD (HOUR(start), 3)) HOUR,
       SUM(count)
  FROM table
 GROUP BY DATE(start) + INTERVAL (HOUR(start) - MOD (HOUR(start), 3)) HOUR
```

The trick to solving this problem of aggregating database rows over blocks of time is, generally, to come up with the appropriate way of truncating the DATETIME or TIMESTAMP values. [Writeup](https://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/sql-reporting-time-intervals/) here.

And if you want to aggregate by 3 hour intervals, with all days gathered into a single result of eight rows, do this.

```
SELECT HOUR(start) - MOD(HOUR(start, 3)),
       SUM(count)
  FROM table 
 GROUP BY HOUR(start) - MOD(HOUR(start, 3))
```

Again, you use an expression to truncate each value to the appropriate block of time.

Comment: I did the last query and applied some formatting at the frontend to make it show like 01h-03h etc...

Answer (score 2):

```
select hr_range,sum(res.cnt)
    from (
        select hour(start) hr,
        case when hour(start) between 0 and 3 then '00h-03h'
            when hour(start) between 4 and 6 then '04h-06h'
            when hour(start) between 7 and 9 then '07h-09h'
            ....
            when hour(start) between 21 and 23 then '21h-23h'
            end as hr_range,
        sum(count) as cnt from `table`
        GROUP BY hour(start)
    )res
group by hr_range
```

I think this is one of the way to solve the issue